# ExtJS Store.filterBy Fails where Store.filter Works

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Ive checked the docs and cant seem to wrap my head around why the store.filter() works until I add a function to it and also the filterBy() fails.

I need the filter to check for 2 things from the record(s).
I need to check:

```
 if(deviceMsgId == 1 || messageType == 'TEXT_MESSAGE')
```

**Store**:

```
 var msgStore =  Ext.create('p7_ui_static.store.DeviceMessageStore', {
    id: 'messageLogStore',
    storeId: storeId,
    remoteFilter: false,
    autoLoad:false,
    ...
    ...
});
```

**Model**:

```
Ext.define('p7_ui_static.model.DeviceMessage', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   ...
   ...
   fields: [
      {
        name: 'deviceMessageTypeId'
      },
      {
        name: 'messageType'
      },
      {
        ...
      }
   ]
});
```

---

***THIS FILTER WORKS ->***

**filter( filters, [value] )**

```
    msgStore.clearFilter(true);
    msgStore.filter([
            { property: 'deviceMsgId', value : 1 }
    ]);
```

---

---

***BUT THIS FILTER FAILS ->***

**filterBy( fn, [scope] )**

```
msgStore.filterBy(function(record){
    return record.get('deviceMsgId' == 1)
});
```

Comment: You didn't post your data. When you say "fails", what does that mean? The function is never called?

Comment: @Evan Trimbol When I say "Fails" I mean that the filter does not filter. The condition {filterFn: function(item) { return item.get("deviceMsgId") == 1}} returns all items, not just items of deviceMsgId == 1.

Comment: You have the store configured with remote filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using filterBy.

```
msgStore.filterBy(function (record){
    if ((record.get('deviceMsgId'))===1 || 
            record.get('messageType')==='TEXT_MESSAGE'){
        return true;
    }
});
```

Also, as a bonus, you can easily filter a store by a property by the following code:

```
msgStore.filter('deviceMsgId',1);
```

Edit: After reviewing the documentation again, it looks like you are correct in returning true. If the function isn't being called, are there any errors being thrown in the console?

Comment: Thanks I see what you are saying. I still was not able to use a filterBy. The method was never being reached.. I still don't know why. I was however able to use a reg filter call, with Fn: ...I posted my solution with taking into consideration boolean as a return as you suggested.